# Opening $modal a second time breaks ui-grid dimension calculations

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, angular-bootstrap

I have an angular-bootstrap `$modal` with a `ui-grid` directive inside. Opening the modal the first time works without issue. The second time, the ui-grid container elements all seem to initially have an `offsetWidth/Height` of 0 which messes up it's internal height calculations - the grid hasn't rendered properly and a parent div is now 400px taller.

Using the [ui-grid auto-resizing](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/213_auto_resizing) works, but I'm eager to avoid such a performance-draining event. I'd debounce it if I had to use it, which I may anyway, but I'm looking for better explanations.

Applying the width/height to the grid directive via CSS doesn't work.

Applying the width/height via inline `style` does work.

Seems like maybe the second time around, the modal renders faster than the css can be applied? I'm at a loss as to why this is happening.

Debugging the element widths inside `ui-grid` (which uses offsetWidth/Height) always shows the correct values the first time, but subsequent openings show all values as **"0"**.

Using Angular 1.3.15, angular-bootrstrap 0.12.1, ui-grid 3.0.0rc2

Calling the modal:

```
$modal.open({
    templateUrl: 'someModal.html',
    controller: 'SomeModalController'
});
```

The template has some form fields, and the directive:

`<div style="width:367px;height:122px;" ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-selection class="grid"></div>`

Inside the main ui-grid directive's `post` method, the offsetWidth/Height of the element is always zero the second time, but if I use `setTimeout` for `10ms`, the sizes are reported correctly.

Comment: Try using the latest unstable. I tried to fix this here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/commit/382f9364e17b09e77277f3559cd29756a035c959 but it hasn't been released in an RC yet. The problem is that $modal alters its dimensions post-render and the grid has to wait for that to happen before determining its "final" size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the code in the modal tutorial - it sets a timeout then calls grid.handleResize.  This may be what you need.  http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/110_grid_in_modal

Comment: Forcing a resize is what I knew was needed already but I'll mark the answer as correct anyway, it's important for future readers. Since in our case the grid container is a fixed size I only call the method once, and never on an interval/window resize.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is occurring every time after the initial load, it's exactly as your said yourself, a timing issue. Solved by either setTimeout, debounce, or ui-grid-auto-resizing.

Comment: I don't need to resize continually so using the auto-resize and debounce are over-kill. I was hoping someone could give me insight as to why the second time around is different - something is still in memory or the cache creates the timing issue. I either have to use the inline style, or *externally* call the grid resize myself with a settimeout. I'm not eager to do either but they're the best solution I have so far.